# How do I move the voice input button to the numeric keyboard in KitKat?

Tags: keyboard, input-methods, 4.4-kitkat

In Android 4.4. KitKat, how do I move the voice input icon, i.e. the one with the microphone icon, from the alphabetic keyboard (next to the spacebar, at left) to the numeric keyboard?

At least up to Android 4.3 It used to be possible to do that via an option in the settings. I checked several times the settings of my Nexus 5 with KitKat, especially the *Languages and input* section, but I cann't find the option.

Is moving the button still possible? What input method and settings options are required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to achieve this is to port over the old keyboard from an older device. This might break stuff, and probably is not the safest bet.

You could install **MultiLing Keyboard** and have a voice button on your numpad.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.klye.ime.latin&hl=en

Comment: So the stock KitKat keyboard no longer provides the feature for moving the microphone icon that Jelly Bean had, right?

Comment: Correctamundo (unfortunately)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running ASOP keyboard, and are on the num pad, you can press and hold the SPACE bar to get the text imput method select. There you can choose Google voice typing.

Esentially
Keyboard -> NUM key -> Long press on space bar -> Google voice input

Comment: I'm actually interested in how to permanently add the microphone icon to the numeric keyboard. I already know how to activate voice input.

Comment: I see. I wonder if there is a way to get a perma voice button, through an app or something.

Comment: I tried Floating Voice Launcher - but it does not do text input, just commands https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evan.floatingvoicelauncher

Answer (score -3):

Try VoiceButton. You can download it here [Dowload VoiceButton](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.borisenkoda.voicebutton)

Comment: This app doesn't do what the questioner is asking for. This is a voice-dialer app, but the question is about voice typing into any app. Also, note that the site's rules require you to declare your interest if you're recommending **your own app** as an answer to a question.

Comment: @DanHulme just as a curiosity how do you know it is his own app?

Comment: @RossC Please come and ask in chat where we can discuss it properly.